# which testing matcher library does angular seed use

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

We set up our angular project using the angular seed project and use jasmine testing framework for our tests.

However, I'm confused and surprised because a lot of the jasmine docs are irrelevant particularly concerning expect/matching logic and spies.

For expectations, I was expecting to be able to use things from the jasmine docs like:

```
expect(...).toBeTruthy()
expect(...).toBeFalsy()
// etc...
```

None of this works and instead it looks like I have to write chai type of code:

```
expect(...).to.be.true;
expect(...).to.be.false;
// etc...
```

And for spies to be able to write expectations like:

```
spyOn(foo, 'setBar');
// ...do some stuff
expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalled();
foo.setBar.calls.reset();
```

but instead I must write:

```
expect(foo.setBar.calls.length).to.equal(1);

// reset calls (this is particularly ugly)
foo.setBar.calls = [];
foo.setBar.argsForCall = [];
```

So two questions:

1. Is there a general recommendation for Jasmine matching over Chai or vice versa? Which one is preferred in the community? Or is there some sort of transition going on that the seed project hasn't caught up to?
2. As a newbie I am preferring Jasmine matching (particularly when it comes to using spies) so how I do I get grunt test to use Jasmine over Chai?

Also it would be nice to get the see project to use a karma-jasmine plugin that uses Jasmine 2.0 vs 1.3.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I should note 2 additional things. We run are tests with grunt and karma-jasmine like:

```
grunt test:unit
```

And our karma.conf.js file looks like:

```
module.exports = function(config){
  config.set({
  basePath : '../',

  files : [
    'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
    'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
    'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/js/**/*.js',
    'test/unit/**/*.js'
  ],

  exclude : [
    'app/lib/angular/angular-loader.js',
    'app/lib/angular/*.min.js',
    'app/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js'
  ],

  autoWatch : true,

  frameworks: ['jasmine'],

  browsers : ['Chrome'],

  plugins : [
    'karma-junit-reporter',
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-firefox-launcher',
    'karma-jasmine'
  ],

  junitReporter : {
    outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
    suite: 'unit'
  }
})}
```

I thought the frameworks: ['jasmine'] would have us using jasmine, whereas frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'], would have us using chai.